# Does the number of times a loop loops slows a program?

Tags: performance, loops

Will this be slower :-

```
for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++)
{
     //doing nothing
}
```

Then this ? :-

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
     //doing nothing
}
```

Comment: Any decent compiler will optimise both loops away completely.

Comment: Depends on the environment totally. Empty loops are usually optimized away by almost any complier. Different in interpreted languages

Comment: @PaulR Wouldn't it optimize it away entirely, since there is nothing done and the only variable is only in scope inside the for?

Comment: Yes - comment updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing nothing in the loop, I believe it will be optimized out by the compiler; however, as a general rule if the contents of the loop are the same then it will take longer to execute the one that runs more frequently.

Comment: What does optimise mean? Will the loop be ignored by the compiler ?

Comment: essentially. The compiler will go through your code and find things that are frivolous, unnecessary, or just needlessly complex and it will either omit code or change it to require less computation to reach the same result.